# Direct Integral: Scalars

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a Borel space $\Omega$.

Regard the Hilbert Space:
$$\mu:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+:\quad\mathcal{H}:=\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega;\mu)$$

Denote the Borel Projections:
$$E:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad E(A)\varphi:=1_A\varphi$$

> Then for Scalar Operators:
>   $$T\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad T=M_\tau\iff ET=TE$$
>   How can I prove this equivalence?

Comment: Are you assuming sigma finite $\mu$?

Comment: @TrialAndError: Sigma-finite is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu$ is sigma-finite, then there are disjoint Borel subsets 
$\{ A_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ of finite $\mu$-measure such that $\bigcup_j A_j=\Omega$. Let $f_j = T1_{A_j}$. Then
$$
     1_{A_k}f_j = 1_{A_k}T1_{A_j}=T1_{A_k\cap A_j} =0 ,\;\;\; k \ne j,\\
             1_{A_j}f_j = f_j.
$$
So each function $f_j$ is supported in $A_j$. Let $f$ be the a.e. unique Borel function for which $1_{A_j}f=f_j$. If $A$ is a Borel subset of finite measure, then $1_A=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}1_A1_{A_j}$ is an orthogonal expansion in $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$. Because $T$ is continuous on $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$,
$$
         T 1_A = T\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}1_{A_j}1_{A}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}T(1_{A_j}1_{A})=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}1_Af_j=f1_A.
$$
Therefore $T\varphi = f\varphi$ for any simple function $\varphi = \sum_{k=1}^{K}\alpha_k\chi_{E_k}$ where $\mu E_k < \infty$ for all $k$.

Comment: Aha nice!!! Can you explain the equality: $\sum_k1_Af_k=f1_A$

Comment: @Freeze_S : Probably the easiest way is $1_A f_j = 1_A1_{A_j}f$ and $\sum_j 1_A 1_{A_j} = 1_A$.

Comment: But it is also not clear a priori: $f1_A\in\mathcal{H}$

Comment: @Freeze_S : $T1_A = f1_A$. Because $A$ is of finite measure, then $1_A \in L^2$, which means that $T1_A \in L^2$. Hence $f1_A = T1_A \in L^2$. Now you see why I wanted sigma finite.

Comment: A priori, $T1_A=f1_A$ is **not** clear. Clearly, $\sum_kf_k1_A\in\mathcal{L}^2$ as **norm** limit. Conversely, $\sum_kf_k1_A=f1_A$ as **pointwise** limit. So the identity is **not** trivial. *(Beppo-Levi?)*

Comment: @Freeze_S : $L^2$ convergence gives you an a.e. convergent subsequence.

Comment: Aha, so it is "stronger" in general.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, indeed! I worked  today on extending the result to direct integrals. Everything alright!!! :D

Comment: **Thanks alot for so much help!!!**